# Java 8 Convert 2D array into Map with key duplication check

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In `java 8` how to convert a 2D `array` into Map using `stream()`. If a key value is already present it should update value as well.

```
String[][] array=new String[][]{{"a","b"},{"a","c"},{"b","d"}};
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
for(String[] arr:array){
   map.put(arr[0],arr[1]);
}
```

I tried this

```
map=Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x[0],x->x[1]));
```

**Error**

> Error:(38, 45) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has
>   incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: java.util.Map
>       upper bounds: java.util.HashMap,java.lang.Object

Comment: Well, this code _will_ update the values... What's the problem then?

Comment: it gives an compile time error arraytype expected

Comment: nope i want to convert it using java 8 stream

Comment: @DavidJones i just wanted know how above code be written in java 8. that is the question. i know these stuffs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an operator that merges duplicate keys:

```
String[][] array = new String[][]{{"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"b", "d"}};

Map<String, String> m = Arrays.stream(array)
                              .collect(Collectors.toMap(  kv -> kv[0],
                                                          kv -> kv[1],
                                                          (oldV, newV) -> newV)
                                                       ));
```

<sub>Formatting those one-liners will be an issue one day..</sub>

Comment: So error is when assign it a HashMap it gives error. But for Map it is working. can you explain why is that

Comment: @Exbury because `toMap` is defined as `public static <T, K, U>
    Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap` with a `Map<>` return type. You'd have to downcast to an implementation manually.

Comment: in this case eclipse doesn't say to cast Map into HashMap. thanks it is working

Comment: Don’t cast a `Map` to `HashMap` when the specification never guarantees that it will be a `HashMap`. If you really need it to be a `HashMap`, use `Collectors.toMap(  kv -> kv[0], kv -> kv[1], (oldV, newV) -> newV, HashMap::new)`